# 1994 Chevy S10 2.2 L LS pickup-no heat or ac and sounds like a fast sewing machine

Tags: chevrolet, hvac, s10, pick-up

1994 Chevy S10 2.2 L LS pickup with rebuilt engine with new thermostat and new radiator. Replaced EGR, fuel filter, and gas cap. Idles loudly like a fast sewing machine. No heat or cool - fan blows. What could be the problem?

Comment: There are a number of things this could be. Not sure what a "fast sewing machine" sounds like. Can you clarify? Also, when you say "no heat or cool", do you mean there is no AC and no heat inside the vehicle? If you had a shop rebuild this engine, they should have taken care of all these things. My suggestion would be to take it back to them to resolve these issues.

Comment: I'd start off by checking the oil right away. "Fast sewing machine" makes me think of valve train noise, which could be due to low or no oil pressure.

Answer (score 1):

I will need more info but here is what I can say.

**for the heater**

- you will need to check to see if the heater core was hooked back up plugged or bypassed.
- I am assuming you let the engine warm up while testing the heater.
- It is less likely that they unhooked the push pull cable to the heater cores valve. it may be a coincidence but this could have also broke.

**for the AC there could be a few things**

- did they put the ac pump back
- did they put the ac radiator back
- if they unhooked anything did they purge the system and refill it with proper refrigerant
- did they put the pumps belt on
- did they hook up the switch wire
- is there now a leak in the system somewhere
- I am assuming this isn't where the sewing machine sound is coming from if it is you might not have the proper refrigerant / coolant in it

**the sewing machine sound**

- can you upload some audio?
- you are sure it is getting enough oil pressure
- new dual or triple valve springs can make noise as they wear in. Not sure if you have these though. below is a picture

until we can hear a recording of it we probably won't be able to pinpoint what the noise might be.

[image]

all the dual and tripple springs can have a tight fit causing them to rub on eachother until they are broken in. as they do this they will make a very distinct noise.